# WPF - Why is there no OnForegroundChanged method in Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-7.0

I am overriding `ContentControl` which inherits from `Control` which has dep prop `Foreground`.. I want to run some custom logic on foreground changed event but there is no `OnForegroundChanged` method to override. There are dozens of other properties changed event handlers but not foreground. Is this by design or am I missing something?

*P.S. I need dependency property event handler only, I am not looking for any other solutions*

Comment: There is also the general [DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyobject.onpropertychanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-dependencyobject-onpropertychanged(system-windows-dependencypropertychangedeventargs)) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no events notifying that any property has changed, but events are not the only way to receive notifications. For example, Binding will receive notification when any Dependency Property changes. And to do this, it does not need to create a derived element with an additional event.

The easiest way to listen for a Dependency Property change is to use a DependencyPropertyDescriptor:

```cs
    var descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ForegroundProperty, control.GetType());
    descriptor.AddValueChanged(control, OnForegroundChanged);
```

`OnForegroundChanged` - value change listener method.

**P.S.** Be careful when using this method with many objects being added or removed. The `AddValueChanged` method creates a strong reference to the listener method (in the example it is OnForegroundChanged). And if it is an instance method, then that instance will be held in memory until `RemoveValueChanged` is called. If you don't do this, there is a possibility of a memory leak.

Comment: yeah i did exactly that.. please add `RemoveValueChanged` because people dont really think any more on what they take from internet. you need to give them full recipe. and without remove it is a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

There is no event that you can subscribe to to get notified when the foreground value is changed (check the [foreground property definition](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Control.cs,144))

One solution is to supply a metadata to your custom control like this

```
static MyCustomControl()
{
    ForegroundProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnForegroundChanged));
}

private static void OnForegroundChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var myCustomControl = (MyCustomControl)d;
    // do something
}
```

This is the same approach used in [`ProgressBar` code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ProgressBar.cs,52).

Comment: I did it differently but this should also work.. However - do I need somehow to clean this up when disposing the control? Dep props are complex animals. Will this override prevent my control from disposing?

Comment: @BoppityBop, I took your recommendation into account and supplemented my answer with an explanation of this nuance.

Comment: @BoppityBop No, you don't have to unsubscribe the event handler, because the publisher is the control itself (unlike the discriptor approach, where the event handler keeps a reference to the custom control). Furthermore, you can check the ProgressBar source code that I've mentioned in my answer (which is a real example demonstrating what you want) and you'll find nothing related to cleaning `OnForegroundChanged` event handler.